# How to find second occurrence of a column based on a condition?

Tags: r

Well, to find the first occurrence of STO1, I set aside a value 1 for STOf. Similarly, I want to find the second occurrence in STO1, to set aside a value 1 for STOs. I tried using some counter, but did not get it right.

```
     ov26<-ov25 %>% 
           group_by(ID) %>% 
           mutate(STOf = { STO1 == 1 } %>% { . * !duplicated(.) } ) 
           %>% ungroup
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: When you say the second occurrence in STO1, occurrence of what? Seems like STO1 is a column in your `ov25` - are you looking for the second occurrence of 1, or?

Comment: @Valeri Voev Yes, STO1 is a column in ov25. Yes, looking for second occurrence of 1.

Comment: Do you want index of 1st and 2nd 1 for each `ID` ? Would this work? `ov25 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(STOf = which(STO1 == 1)[1], STO1 = which(STO1 == 1)[2])
` ?

Comment: @RonakShah - you probably meant `STOs = which(STO1 == 1)[2]`

Comment: The code is not working :( Suppose I have a dataset of ov25 - column, STO1 with values {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1....} group by id. The STOf looks at first occurence of 1, I want STOs to check the second occurrence of 1 in STO1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but just in case --- could you `group_by` both `ID` and `STO1`, something like:

```
ov25 %>% 
  group_by(ID, STO1) %>% 
  mutate(STOf = if_else(STO1 == 1 & row_number() == 1, 1, 0),
         STOs = if_else(STO1 == 1 & row_number() == 2, 1, 0))
```

this would put a 1 in `STOf` for first row in the group, where `STO1` is 1. Similar approach for `STOs`.